# sharepoint web app and jquery combination

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, sharepoint

Within SharePoint...

I can create web parts which are ASP.NET web apps, which allows me to get information about the current user (groups they are in, username, etc.).

I can create web parts which allow me to manipulate fields on SharePoint forms.

But I have not found a way to be able to combine the two things.

I can't access the content of one web part from the other kind (WebApp Page Viewer & Jquery Content Editor Web Part being the two kinds).

What I would like to be able to do is create a web service and then consume it with a jquery ajax call, but I keep getting a js "Access Denied" message.

Any help? Any ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving your .js , xslt ...type files into a location inside SharePoint, e.g. temporarily put them in the style library. Reference to them in the location inside SharePoint, and see if that works...

The problem may that you're trying to load a resource off the file system from a web part which some cases gives an 'access denied' error.